# Where can I see the PubSub service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, service-accounts, google-iam

The PubSub service account is `service-<PROJECT_NUMBER>@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

The command [described here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures) to create an IAM policy binding succeeds, which shows that the service account exists.

But it does not appear in

- the list of service accounts in the console `https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?project=<PROJECT>` (screenshot below)
- nor in the IAM permissions list `https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=<PROJECT>` , even when I check "Include Google-provided role grants"
- nor in the output of `gcloud iam service-accounts list --project <PROJECT>`.

Where can I see this service account listed?

[image]

Comment: Can you try the below [command](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies#before_you_begin) and check if you can see the Pub/Sub Google managed service account. Also can you provide the screenshot of the IAM page by checking ‘Include Google-provided role grants' also hiding all the sensitive information?

`gcloud beta asset search-all-iam-policies`

Comment: There is no problem generating a policy for this SA. It just dos not appear in the GUI, including the IAM page. I'd rather not share it because it is alll sensitive, but I searched it for sa-pubsub, making sure that all accounts are listed (i.e., there are no multiple pages)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `service-<PROJECT_NUMBER>@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com` is a [Google managed service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#google-managed), therefore, you can see it in the list YOUR PROJECT service accounts.

In addition, you have granted this service account on a TOPIC resource and not on a PROJECT resource. Therefore, when you go on the iam-admin page, you can see the service account at the PROJECT ressource.

Anyway, you could be able to view it in the iam-admin page by checking `Include Google-provided role grants`

[image]

Because you have granted the service account at TOPIC resource level, you can see it in the TOPIC page

Go to the [topic page](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/topic/list), check a topic and go to the right-hand panel, in the permission section and look at the role that  you grant on the service account. You will find it

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It does not appear in the IAM user list, even with the "Include Google..." option enabled, It does not appear in the SA page (see added screenshot) nor with the gcloud iam service-accounts list --project <PROJECT> .  Strange. However, it does appear in Topic permissions.

Comment: The SA page, it's normal. The IAM page with the Include Google-provided option, it depends if the service account has permission at project level or not (apparently not), and YES, you see it a Topic level because the command that you ran is `gcloud pubsub topics add-iam-policy-binding` -> you add policy binding at the pubsub/topic level.

Comment: Thank you: "it depends if the service account has permission at project level" So I guess that that is the explanation. It seems problematic that this Google-managed SA is hidden until you create a policy.

Comment: Agree and disagree. Agree when you begin and you want to know/see what happens in your project. Disagree because when you use automation and script, you don't care to see it or not, it's automatic and you don't need to worry about it. All depends on the stage of your journey!

Comment: The fact that the service account doesn't appear under "Service Accounts" is indeed a serious bug in Google Cloud, but worse is that the SA doesn't appear anywhere even when it has permission to use some of your resources. It makes it difficult to understand and maintain GCP security.

Comment: There is user managed service accounts and google managed service account. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#google-managed